# change user password who has expire password date with sshpass

Tags: linux, ssh, script, shell-script, ansible

My servers have password date expire user. I want to write a script or ansible playbook for this. I try below command but I have failed. Is there any way do this with ansible? or Which command can I use for change password for the expired user?

`sshpass -e ssh username@ip | echo -e "old_password\nnew_password\nnew_password"`

`sshpass -e ssh username@ip 'echo -e "old_password\nnew_password\nnew_password"'`

Comment: *If* anything like this, then `echo … | sshpass …`, not the other way around. In a pipeline data flows from left to right.

Comment: I try this: echo -en "old_password\nnew_password\nnew_password\n" | sshpass -e ssh -tt username@ip but there is no change stuck in the (current) UNIX password: